# JavaScript Date Object - Strange Behavior

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and attempting to convert some server-side code to it using NodeJS.  A snippet is below; in general it takes a date and subtracts 2 weeks from it.

Can anyone explain why the below happens?

```
var currentDate = new Date('05/12/2014 14:32');
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 14);
console.log(typeof currentDate);
console.log(currentDate);
```

Output:

```
object
Mon Apr 28 2014 14:32:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

Now, all is well.  I've managed to subtract 14 days off of my date.  However, it really isn't the 'currentDate' anymore so I want to assign it to say, 'futureDate'

```
var currentDate = new Date('05/12/2014 14:32');
var futureDate = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 14);
console.log(typeof futureDate);
console.log(futureDate);
```

Output:

```
number
1398713520000
```

Ick.  That's no good.  it looks like it returned milliseconds since epoch or something as a number.  Bad times.  But how come if I do this, it does work...

```
var currentDate = new Date('05/12/2014 14:32');
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 14);
var futureDate = currentDate;
console.log(typeof futureDate);
console.log(futureDate);
```

Output:

```
object
Mon Apr 28 2014 14:32:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

It just makes no logical sense to me.  JavaScript is hurting my head.  I'd be grateful for any help in understanding what is happening here.  I know I can proceed and my script will work, but I'd like to understand what is going on.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually happens in your code now is this :

> var futureDate = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 14);

You're setting the date of **currentDate** to `currentDate.getDate() - 14`.
`currentDate.setDate` returns the **integer** equivalent of that new date, and you save that to **futureDate**.

You should save it as a Date, and not as an integer as it currently is.

It's because `futureDate` is currently not a Date. `currentDate.getDate() - 14` will return just a number, but for you to make it into a Date, you should initialize `futureDate` as a date first, then use `futureDate.setDate` to assign it a new date value.

```
var futureDate = new Date();
futureDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 14);
```